# Priority Queues: Enqueue returns 'None' instead of int value

Tags: python, priority-queue

I am having problems with my PriorityQueue class in python. I think I set it up all the way and now I'm trying to test it, but I keep getting the word "None" when I print out the value I am enqueuing which isn't right.

This is my test code, following that is my Output and Expected Output:

```
from PriorityQueue import PriorityQueue

PQ = PriorityQueue()


print(PQ.enqueue(1, 10))
print(PQ.enqueue(2, 5))
print(PQ.enqueue(3, 90))
print(PQ)
print(PQ.size())
```

Output:

```
None
None
None
<PriorityQueue.PriorityQueue object at 0x01EE5250>
2
```

Expected Output:

```
10
5
90
90,5,10
2
```

Why would it print the word None? I have no idea why it would do that. Here is my PriorityQueue class where it gets the functions from.

```
#PriorityQueue.py
from MyHeap import Heap


class PriorityQueue(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.heap = Heap()

    def enqueue(self, priority, item):
        '''Post: Item is inserted with specified priority in the PQ.'''
        self.heap.insert((priority, item))

    def first(self):
        '''Post: Returns but does not remove the highest priority item from the PQ.'''
        return self.heap.size()


    def dequeue(self):
        '''Post: Removes and returns the highest priority item from the PQ.'''
        if self.heap.size() is None:
            raise ValueError("Error your queue is empty.")
        x = self.first()
        self.heap.delete_max()
        return x

    def size(self):
        '''Post: Returns the number of items in the PQ.'''
        return self.heap.size()
```

All these functions, or well most of them take from my custom heap class which is this.

```
class Heap(object):

    def __init__(self, items=None):

        '''Post: A heap is created with specified items.'''

        self.heap = [None]
        if items is None:
            self.heap_size = 0
        else:
            self.heap += items
            self.heap_size = len(items)
            self._build_heap()

    def size(self):

        '''Post: Returns the number of items in the heap.'''

        return self.heap_size

    def _heapify(self, position):

        '''Pre: Items from 0 to position - 1 satisfy the Heap property.
           Post: Heap Property is satisfied for the entire heap.'''

        item = self.heap[position]
        while position * 2 <= self.heap_size:
            child = position * 2
            # If the right child, determine the maximum of two children.
            if (child != self.heap_size and self.heap[child+1] > self.heap[child]):
                child += 1
            if self.heap[child] > item:
                self.heap[position] = self.heap[child]
                position = child
            else:
                break
        self.heap[position] = item

    def delete_max(self):

        '''Pre: Heap property is satisfied
           Post: Maximum element in heap is removed and returned. '''

        if self.heap_size > 0:
            max_item = self.heap[1]
            self.heap[1] = self.heap[self.heap_size]
            self.heap_size -= 1
            self.heap.pop()
            if self.heap_size > 0:
                self._heapify(1)
            return max_item

    def insert(self, item):

        '''Pre: Heap Property is Satisfied.
           Post: Item is inserted in proper location in heap.'''

        self.heap_size += 1
        # extend the length of the list.
        self.heap.append(None)
        position = self.heap_size
        parent = position // 2
        while parent > 0 and self.heap[parent] < item:
            # Move the item down.
            self.heap[position] = self.heap[parent]
            position = parent
            parent = position // 2
        # Puts the new item in the correct spot.
        self.heap[position] = item

    def _build_heap(self):

        ''' Pre: Self.heap has values in 1 to self.heap_size
           Post: Heap property is satisfied for entire heap. '''

        # 1 through self.heap_size.

        for i in range(self.heap_size // 2, 0, -1): # Stops at 1.
            self._heapify(i)

    def heapsort(self):

        '''Pre: Heap Property is satisfied.
           Post: Items are sorted in self.heap[1:self.sorted_size].'''

        sorted_size = self.heap_size

        for i in range(0, sorted_size -1):
            # Since delete_max calls pop to remove an item, we need to append a dummy value to avoid an illegal index.
            self.heap.append(None)
            item = self.delete_max()
            self.heap[sorted_size - i] = item
```

Could anyone tell me the problem of why it isn't working? I thought it was supposed to return the value. I also know I need an **iter** for my PriorityQueue class, but I don't know what it would look like. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Don't try to tack unrelated questions onto the end of an existing question; if you need help with an `__iter__` method, create a new question showing a minimal example and where you're stuck.

Comment: By the way, to get the fourth line the way you want it, you need `__str__` (or `__repr__`--and you may want both, doing different things). If you don't understand and searching the tutorial and SO doesn't explain it, that's another new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `enqueue` method doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `None`.

If you were expecting Python to be like, say, Ruby or Scheme, and return the value of the last expression evaluated--well, Python isn't Ruby; one of the biggest differences is that, unlike Ruby, Python is a statement-based language where not everything is an expression, so there usually *is* no "last expression", just a last statement, which has no value.

Meanwhile, returning `None` from a method that mutates `self` is considered the Pythonic thing to do (see `list.append`, for example), so you actually wrote your code correctly, even if you didn't intend to. :)

This means that Python doesn't lend itself to the method-chaining "fluent style" that's popular in some other languages. This is a deliberate design choice; although Guido has never really articulated why, consider that a single giant expression doesn't let you see the flow of control through vertical space and horizontal indentation the way a chain of statements does, discourages you from giving meaningful names to meaningful intermediate values, is harder to debug with tracebacks or a traditional step debugger, etc.